# codeigniter - using regex for method in csrf_exclude_uris

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

Is there a way to use regex in the csrf_exclude_uris array so that I only need to define the controller?

I know I can use regex for the end parameter like so:

```
controller/method-name/[0-9]+
```

But what I want is to just exclude the controller and any method like so:

```
controller/[a-z\-]+
```

or

```
controller/[a-z\-]+/[0-9]+
```

Haven't found any examples doing it anywhere and since it is not working, just wondering if anyone knows if it is actually possible, or if you see something wrong with what I am trying.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try:
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array("controller_name/.*+");